# Add project as a dependency management to parent pom

Tags: maven

I've got the following task:
1) Create 3 java projects A, B and C that use  a single parent  pom.xml located on the containing (“parent”) root folder 
2) The “parent” pom.xml should double as  parent  and  aggregator  at the root dir.
3) Create a project D with a pom.xml that lists all dependency versions that are used in the java projects
4) In the “parent” pom.xml add D as dependency management, and build A, B, C as
submodules.

My question is how to implement 3 and 4.

I wrote the following code:

pom.xml in project D:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>d</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

Pom.xml in project "parent":

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <revision>0.0.1</revision>
    <changelist>-SNAPSHOT</changelist>
    <sha1/>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>a</module>
    <module>b</module>
    <module>c</module>
    <module>d</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>d</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>b</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>c</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13-beta-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
           <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
           <version>1.16.0</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Thanks!

Dave

Comment: You're using some weird dynamic versioning - first try keep it simple and use hardcoded versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference `pom` file (not `jar` which is the default type), and the scope needs to be `import` for `dependencyManagement` section be "copied" into your current pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>d</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Stanislav! Thank you for your answer. Maybe I was not very clear. I've edited the question. Would you take a look, please? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah.. You're trying to declare the versions of your own modules. I remember I tried that once and failed. So not sure if that's going to work. But the task that you were given doesn't ask that - it asks to declare _3d-party_ dependencies in D. They will be used in A, B, C. Declare the versions of your own modules in main parent POM instead.

Comment: I still don't understand:( Could you give me a code example of how 3d-party dependencies should be declared in D and how they should appear in Parent pom.xmp in dependency management section, please?

Comment: I've added your code. Now I am getting the following error: The dependencies of type=pom and with scope=import form a cycle: parent:d:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> parent:d:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ parent:d:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: The error states that you have cyclic references. Are you referencing D in D? Or maybe you declared a parent in your D?

Comment: I updated the code. You can see my both pom.xml files now

Comment: As you can see, I declared parent in D, but without that declaration there is an error "Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact parent:d:pom:0.0.1-
 SNAPSHOT"

Comment: You can't have cyclic references. That's it, you can't beat it. You need to fix your "Could not find artifact" properly e.g. try `install`ing this module into your local repo.

Comment: Could you give me a piece of code how to do that, please?

Comment: I tried to run the command: "mvn install:install-file -Dfile="./d/target/d-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" -DgroupId=parent -DartifactId=d -Dversion="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" -Dpackaging=pom" but it still gave me the same error "Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact parent:d:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: As I said - you should remove a parent from D. It can't have parent and be a dependency of that parent. If you upload your code to github or bitbucket I can take a look and send you a PR.